# Google Appe Engine NDB cross domain

Tags: google-app-engine

Is it possible to have 2 different domains sharing the one/same NDB?

Example:

In http://mydomain1.appspot.com

```
r = MyData("myid"="say","words"="hello world!")
r.put()
```

In other site, at http://mydomain2.appspot.com

```
q = MyData.query(MyData.myid == "say")
r = q.get()
self.response.out.write(r.words)
>>> output: hello world!
```

Is it possible? Is there an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two applications (GAE appid's) cannot share the same datastore.

But two domains like www.example1.com and www.example2.com can point to the same application. And you can use wildcard subdomains:
http://googleappengine.blogspot.nl/2009/08/new-features-in-124.html